# Is Div 3d Rotation with JQuery possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is Div 3d Rotation with JQuery possible? We like layout of website to be same like Apple. CSS 3 is not a option as 3d transform only supported in chrome and safari

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible. There is a plugin. You can get it by search it with google as jquery 3d cube plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Possible? Yes, sort of, but jQuery wouldn't have so much to do with anything. You could write JavaScript code to perform 3D transformation and render stuff to a canvas, but you would have to consider performance issues.

If you need 3D transformations, you need CSS3 or WebGL or possibly Canvas rendering. There are a few libraries that can help you with this:

- [Canvas 3d JS Library](http://www.c3dl.org/)
- [A list of 3d libraries](http://javascript.open-libraries.com/multimedia/3d/fantastic-javascript-3d-libraries/)